# PowerShell: Unexpected sequence type after select-object

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a little PowerShell script which should clean up my Visual Studio projects. My strategy is to find all project files (e.g. *.csproj) in a subdirectory. The parent folder of a project file should be the project directory. From there it is easy to get to the bin and obj subfolders.

With the following snippet I wanted to find all project folders:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path $start_dir -Include *.csproj | select Directory
```

I would expect that this statement evaluates to a sequence of System.IO.DirectoryInfo objects. To my surprise this is not the case. In fact you get a sequence of Selected.System.IO.FileInfo:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path $start_dir -Include *.csproj | select Directory | gm


TypeName: Selected.System.IO.FileInfo

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Directory   NoteProperty System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory=C:\dev\proj\ART\Sources\ART.Adapter
```

Can somebody explain this behaviour? Does somebody know another statement which evaluates to a squence of DirectoryInfo objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path $start_dir -Include *.csproj | select -expand Directory | % { [io.directoryinfo]$_ }
```

or

```
$dirs = [io.directoryinfo[]](Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path $start_dir -Include *.csproj | select -expand Directory )
```

In your code you have in `$dirs` an `[object[]]` of `[pscustomobject]`,
you need to get the `[string]` value using `-expand` in `select-object` and cast each value to an `[io.diredtoryinfo]` object.

Answer (score 1):

The Select-Object cmdlet always produces a selected object of that object type.

Try this for getting a collection of DirectoryInfo objects:

```
$dirs = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path $start_dir -Include *.csproj).Directory
```